# PHP - Fetch week's first-last date if start-end date falls midweek

Tags: php, date

```
$month_year = 'JUL-2015';
$cal = $Calendar->getweek(date("m", strtotime($month_year)), date("Y", strtotime($month_year)));
$call_arr = array();
    foreach ($cal['start_day'] as $cal_key => $cal_no) {
        $call_arr[] = $cal_no . " - " . $cal['end_day'][$cal_key];
    }
```

The above outputs week range for the month of `JUL-2015` like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1 - 5
    [1] => 6 - 12
    [2] => 13 - 19
    [3] => 20 - 26
    [4] => 27 - 31
)
```

The first week of `JUL-2015` starts from Wednesday. How could I achieve following when user selects `Start-End` date from Calendar

1. Check if start-date`(1-Jul)` and end-date`(5-Jul)` for first week of
   July falls mid-week and does not start from Monday
2. If start/end date for any week starts from mid-week i.e. not from
   `Monday`, how to fetch the starting date of that week ? In our case it
   would be `(29-JUN)`
3. For last week of `JUL-2015(27 - 31)`, the starting date would be
   `27-JUL` and end date would be `2-AUG` for that specific week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$day = '2015-05-04';
$weekDay = date('w', strtotime($day));

$weekStart = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($day . ' -'.$weekDay. ' days'));
$weekEnd = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($day .' +'.(6-$weekDay). ' days'));

echo $weekStart . ' + ' . $weekEnd;
```

Comment: Assuming it for the month `MAY-2015` week 1 (1-3) how could I fetch `start_date = 27-APR and end_date = 3-MAY` by start and end date inputs as `1-MAY-2015` and `3-MAY-2015` respectively ?

Comment: my representation shows how you could find weekStart and weekEnd you can find for any date by changing the date on $today variable, suppose if you want to find for date 27-APRIL-2015 you could change the variable as follow $today = date('w',strtotime('2015-04-07'));

Comment: This `$today = date('w',strtotime('2015-05-01')); 
            $weekStart = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-'.$today. ' days'));
            $weekEnd = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+'.(6-$today). ' days'));` outputs  `5,2015-07-16,2015-07-22` respectively. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Ammadu: Appreciate your response, changing date as `$day = 2015-05-01`, it should output `04-27-2015 + 05-03-2015` but its giving `04-26-2015 + 05-02-2015`. One day is incremented

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy changing $weekDay variable as follow would adjust it $weekDay = date('w', strtotime($day))-1; in my code I haven't adjusted the week start date assuming it should be sunday, but you are actually looking for monday right.

Comment: Yes, my week starts on Monday and ends on Sunday. And would the code would work without giving end date as input. It really works for start date as of now